# How do I create a custom Facebook share dialog box passing parameters?

Tags: facebook, dialog, share, lightbox

I've seen a few posts here and around the interwebs explaining how to create a custom Facebook share dialog box for my website.

But I have found a few differences from the average situation to mine:

1- I want a custom area in my page to open and close when people click on a button (the share button)

2- I want share the content in a lightbox, not the page's content. For example, we have a list of products, each product will open in a lightbox. I want to share information about this product that is now open in a lightbox

I saw someone talking about the Javascript SDK, but it the installation guide it tells me to set the APP_ID, but don't have any App create for my website. Do I have to create one to use this SDK?

I also found this pattern

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=a title&p[summary]=a description &p[url]=http://www.linkhere.com&p[images][0]=http://www.linkhere.com/image.jpg
```

If I copy and paste this to the address bar it works. but the user is redirected to a new page. that is not nice.

and I tried this with the pattern said above, but couldnt make it work

```
<a href="#" 
          onclick="
            window.open(
                'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href),
              'facebook-share-dialog', 
              'width=626,height=436');
            return false;">
          Share on Facebook
        </a>
```

It doesn't accept the parameters I am trying to pass.

Do any of you know how to solve this problem? Will it be by changing the 'content' of metatags? What are your solutions?

@EDIT

Just answered with the solution I used

@EDIT 2

Updated with v2.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I did to solve the problem in my website:

First I added the tools Facebook provides me:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR APP ID GOES HERE',                        // App ID from the app dashboard      
      status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
      xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
    });
    // channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel file for x-domain comms
    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>
```

Then I created a function shareOnFacebook that opens the sharer and the button that will call this function

```
var globalFacebookShareObject = {} //will be set when I click on a product, on a picture, on a comment or post, or whatever I want to share on Facebook or when I load the page

function shareOnFacebook(){
    FB.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        name: globalFacebookShareObject.name,
        link: globalFacebookShareObject.link,
        caption: 'R$ '+globalFacebookShareObject.caption,
        picture: globalFacebookShareObject.picture,
        description: globalFacebookShareObject.description
    }, function(response) {
        if(response && response.post_id){}
        else{}
    });
}

<button onclick='shareOnFacebook()'>Share it!</button>
```

@edit at 10/01/2015
Still working for v2.2

Refere to [Feed method](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.2) to understand how to create the share dialog (I am using the `feed` method that seems to be more flexible)

And to [Quickstart](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.2)
To understand how to import the Javascript SDK to your page

Comment: I believe `feed` is deprecated now in APIv2. Only share is supported and it doesn't appear to allow overriding OG properties.

Comment: @VictorFerreira why we should create a facebook app?if i make a website for someone should i use my app or i should ask them to create a app?

Answer (score 11):

This is an old question, but here is what works for me:

```
window.open(
        'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=a title&p[summary]=a description &p[url]=http://www.linkhere.com&p[images][0]=http://www.linkhere.com/image.jpg',
        'facebook-share-dialog', 
        'width=626,height=436'
    );
```

basically all I had to do was remove the /sharer/ from the facebook url. I am guessing it is a typo in the documentation.

Comment: Now this approach will not work, its tooks details from open graph or the given url. especially using with canonical it get stuck.

Comment: Open Graph is a different story. It tells Facebook what to share.

Answer (score 0):

December 2017: Custom object sharing is being deprecated. Your best bet from now on is to create another page for that object and have the respective meta tags facebook looks for in there. More info here: [developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog)